# npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.16299 node & npm not match the same version , how i can solve this error?

Tags: node.js, npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExOjs.png)[image]i don't know why doing this realy but i think the node js not match npm version

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: You should download the latest version from the Node.js website.

Comment: Also, why are you using `curl`? `curl` only works on Linux and macOS.

Comment: ok iam already have install the version but still not match

Comment: no iam use windows 10

Comment: Yes, I can see that you are using Windows (from your Command Prompt window), but I was saying that the `curl` command isn't built-in to Windows, and you were trying to run it, which resulted in an error.

Comment: oki iam understand what you talk about but iam not using curl you can see the image again , can i set the npm version with node ? any suggestion

Comment: You can install npm from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I'll try my best to answer.

---

Basically, to update `npm`, you can simply update it from the actual npm library, as so.

```
$ npm install -g npm@8.6.0
```

This will update `npm` globally without affecting the Node.js version.

---

To install Node.js, [download the installer](https://nodejs.org/), then, run it, and it should install Node.js and npm to the latest version.

Comment: Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\AL - ELMIA> npm install -g npm@8.6.0
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.16299
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\AL - ELMIA\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "npm@8.6.0"
npm ERR! node v16.14.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request

Comment: that i got after add this commend npm install -g npm@8.6.0